# Lennard Jones Potential Simulation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-integration

What equation would use for Lennard-Jones Potential Simulation for the Explicit Euler Method, would it be the original equation or the derivative of the Lennard Jones Potential for calculating the force between each particle at each timestep?

Answer (score 0):

The force of the Leonard-Jones Potential is computed through its gradient. Using the Newton's Second Law integrating all the molecular forces allows you to time step from one state to the other (integration of the equations of motion). You can use any time integration scheme for this. Check these references for further information:

http://phycomp.technion.ac.il/~talimu/md2.html

http://phys.ubbcluj.ro/~tbeu/MD/C2_for.pdf